# How to join two tmux windows into one, as panes?

Tags: session, split, tmux

I have two tmux windows, with a single pane in each, and I would like to join these two panes together into a single window as a horizontal split panes.  How could I do that?

Comment: here is a good answer to the question.  http://superuser.com/questions/266567/tmux-how-can-i-link-a-window-as-split-window

Answer (score 267, accepted):

Actually I found the way to do that. Suppose the two windows are number 1 and 2. Use

```
join-pane -s 2 -t 1
```

This will move the 2<sup>nd</sup> window as a pane to the 1<sup>st</sup> window. The opposite command is `break-pane`

Comment: Actually `join-pane` is to move one pane into another, not to move window. `join-pane -s 2 -t 1` does not put two windows side by side, but two panes instead. It's just that the windows happen to have only one pane each. If you have two windows both of which have multiple panes, to put two of panes, say they are pane `0.0` and `1.0`, side by side, you can: 1) create a new window 2) move pane `0.0` to pane `2.0` 3) move pane `1.0` to pane `2.0` 4) kill pane `2.0`. Pane `0.0` means the 0th pane of the 0th window.

Comment: As already said by @Hong the answer solves the issue but the explanation is incorrect. Two windows can be joined and will result into 1 window splitted into 2 panes. And the example of window numbers can also confuse ppl because as the question is made there is no mention of a third window so to put it correctly it should be window number 0 and 1 (tmux starts always with window 0) Maybe the OP could change the question aswell the answer that way that the question will be re-opend and the answer is correctly formulated. But that is my opinion.

Comment: is there a keyboard shortcut for this that I can map to?

Comment: Note to enter `join-pane ...` you first enter Ctrl-B then :

Comment: @IshanKhare this is good shortcut: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14301/337677

Comment: One thing to note that this doesn't work if you're already on the mentioned 2nd window.

Comment: @RNA Great many thanks! However this seems not to work if there are already several panes in the windows to merge. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 24):

Alternatively, if you don't want to specify the window names when calling `join-pane`, you can also mark the pane you want to join into the current window.

Let's say you want to move a pane from window 2 to window 1. Here's how to do it:

1. Switch to window 2.
2. Mark the desired pane with <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>.
3. Switch to window 1.
4. Call `join-pane`: <kbd>Prefix</kbd> `:join-pane`

Comment: This is by far the more useful answer for me -- thank you!